# Customize JSON key name in C# SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a C# class with the name `_Numeric` as Numeric values are not allowed.I would like to serialize this to a JSON but replace `_Numeric` to Numeric in JSON Keys.
How can I write some custom JSON

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
class TestNumeric
{
   
    public InnerNumeric innerNumeric;
    public string name;


    public TestNumeric()
    {
        name = "Test Name";
        innerNumeric = new InnerNumeric
        {

            _22 = new _22
            {
                value = "value _22"

            },
            someClass = new SomeClass {
                value = "some Class value"

            }
        };    
    }

    public class InnerNumeric
    {
        public _22 _22;
        public SomeClass someClass;
       
    }

    public class _22
    {
        public string value;
    }


    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string value;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestNumeric data = new TestNumeric();

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

    }

}
```

the JSON output is

```
    {
  "innerNumeric": {
    "_22": {
      "value": "value _22"
    },
    "someClass": {
      "value": "some Class value"
    }
  },
  "name": "Test Name"
}
```

How can I translate this to by replacing `_22` with a custom name like `22`

```
{
  "innerNumeric": {
    "22": {
      "value": "value _22"
    },
    "someClass": {
      "value": "some Class value"
    }
  },
  "name": "Test Name"
}
```

using Newtonsoft.Json package we can add `[JsonProperty("22")]`,how to achieve same with JavaScriptSerializer from (System.Web.Script.Serialization)?

Comment: So you want to change the property name when you serialize, right?

Comment: yes using System.Web.Script.Serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize how the serializer serializes your property names by using an attribute (this is for the new `System.Text.Json`):

```
public class InnerNumeric
{
    [JsonPropertyName("22")]
    public _22 _22;
    public SomeClass someClass;
}
```

That will serialize and deserialize an object that has `{ "22":...}` property name

Answer (score -1):

I think you cant name a property that starts with a number then serializer set an underscore at the beginning.